# service got stuck and triggered the timer multiple times

Tags: .net, vb.net, multithreading, timer

I created a windows service in vb that wait for files at a specific folder. If there is a new file it will be scanned and moved to the correct folder. The service worked fine for a week but then something happend and I don't know why. The service got stuck for like 50 seconds. The timer is set to 10 seconds.

Problem is that the timer triggered the code for reading and moving also 5 times. I guess you already know what happend. 5 threads tried to read and move the same file and created an exception war. The service crashed and had to be restarted manually. But I can not check daily if the service is running so I would like to improve something. Here is some parts of my code:

Search for files:

```
Private Sub Listener_Tick(source As Object, e As ElapsedEventArgs)
    Try
        Dim al As New ArrayList
        SearchFiles("*.hl7", My.Settings.GetFolder, al)
        Dim FoundFile As String = ""
        Try
            FoundFile = al.Item(0)
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
        If FoundFile.Length = 0 Then
            If AtWork = True Then
                LogLine = "[INFO] No files left :) Service wait for files..." & FoundFile : WriteToLog()
                AtWork = False
            End If
        Else
            If AtWork = False Then
                LogLine = "[INFO] File(s) found. Work started!" : WriteToLog()
                AtWork = True
```

Read (not included) and Move file:

```
Try
    File.Move(FoundFile, FoundwithHL7)
    Catch ex As Exception
    LogLine = "[ERROR][EXCEPTION] HL7 import failed - " & hl7File & " - " & ex.ToString : WriteToLog()
End Try
```

Is it possible that even if the service got stuck that I will not create 5 individually threads? I thought the Boolean "AtWork" fix the problem, but this is not the case if 5 different threads are start the work at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) U can always stop timer till work is done. And Resume timer

```
       Private Sub Listener_Tick(source As Object, e As ElapsedEventArgs)
        Listener.Enable = False ' u can alweys stop timer till task is not done
        Try
            '... Task
        Catch ex As Exception
        Finally
            Listener.Enable = True ' and resume at end
        End Try
    End Sub
```

2) if u wana be sure about thread, u can use synhlock, so only one thread can execute method at this same time.

```
        Private LockObj As New Object
    Sub DoSomthing()
        SyncLock LockObj ' Lock don't let other threat to work at this same time
            Try
                'Code Task
            Catch ex As Exception

            End Try
        End SyncLock
    End Sub
enter code here
```

3) U can also use file Watcher to trigger on newly created or edited file in directory and timer is not needed
[system.io.filesystemwatcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: #1 does not work
#2 could work. I added it and lets see if this fix the issue.

Comment: how u initialize timer ? u sure if is running all time and is not reinitialize ? is u got many timer instance u will be produce more events, be sure if u use one all time. #1 should work, log hash Listener and check if is changes over time, should not. if not Start and Stop will be work for this case.

Comment: The problem with the synclock method is if the main work of the method starts taking more than 10 seconds to work. You create an endless convoy of timer callbacks waiting to acquire the lock. If there's significant work, you could easily exhaust resources just on threads waiting to find out that there's no real work to do. That's why I advocate an independent (single) thread rather than trying to throttle timer callbacks.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever yes your right but the solution works perfect for this project. The timer is (believe it or not) necessary since the service also do something else then just reading and coping files.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want one thread at a time to perform some activity, I'd usually dedicate a thread to that task rather than setting up a timer and then worrying about re-entrancy issues, as you currently are.

As a sketch, you would have a thread and some form of event (to watch for shutdown). You run an endless loop where you:

1. record the current time in a variable
2. do your processing work
3. compute how long you want to sleep for, based on the time *now* and the time you recorded in step 1 and whatever you're currently using as your timer interval.<sup>1</sup>
4. Instead of sleeping, do a wait on your shutdown event, using the calculated time from step 3 as the timeout value.
5. If step 4 resulted in a timeout, return to step 1. Otherwise, exit the loop

---

<sup>1</sup>E.g. if the time from step 1 was 10:40, if the time now is 10:45, and the timer interval is 10 minutes then we want to sleep for 5 minutes. If the timer interval is 2 minutes, then our current run overran, so we compute a sleep interval of 0 minutes. We still do the wait step in step 4 though so that shutdown can still happen in an orderly fashion.

Comment: Why I should calculate the time instead of using fixed waiting value? Sounds a bit random and useless? 
the program should run 24/7 so a shutdown is not planned.

Comment: @MarcoSadowski - so that you get code that runs, say, every 10 seconds. Not 10 seconds + the amount of time it takes to perform its processing. Especially if the processing time starts taking more than 10 seconds itself, at which point you don't really want to sleep. And being a well-behaved service that doesn't force windows to forcibly terminate your process means that you should implement shutdown behaviour. Windows does need to reboot from time to time, if nothing else.